# Pygame why isn't my collision working?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

I am trying to detect when two of my sprites collide. The first thing I did was create a rectangle around my player (called player.img) then another around the trees that I want to detect (called background.treesrect). I set the coordinates of the players rectangle equal to the coordinates that update when the player moves by the user pressing keys but the players rectangle doesnt move. Then I used the sprite.colliderect(sprite) function to detect if they collide and it doesnt detect. Can someone show my why my player rectangle isnt updating and anything else that may be wrong?

**EDIT** I just figured out the collision by putting the function that draws the rectangle into the game loop instead of the player class but I ran into another weird problem. The rectangle moves faster than the player sprite for some reason and I cant figure out how to make the player sprite on top of the background and not show the player rectangle.

```
                            import pygame
                            import sys
                            from pygame.locals import *

                            #starts the program
                            pygame.init()

                            white = (255, 255, 255)
                            black = (0, 0, 0)
                            red = (255, 0, 0)
                            blue = (0, 0, 255)
                            green = (0, 255, 0)
                            yellow = (255, 255, 153)

                            #creates a window of 800x600
                            setDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
                            pygame.display.set_caption('Menu')

                            img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png')

                            class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                                    def __init__(self):
                                            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                                            self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert()
                                            self.imgx = 10
                                            self.imgy = 10
                                            self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()
                                            self.x = self.imgx
                                            self.y = self.imgy
                                            self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32))

                                    def draw(self):
                                            self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)

                                    def load(self, filename):
                                            self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert_alpha()               



                            class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                                    def __init__(self):
                                             pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                                             self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\background.png').convert()
                                             self.img2 = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\trees1.png').convert()
                                             self.treesx = 0
                                             self.treesy = 70
                                             self.treesrect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255),pygame.Rect(self.treesx, self.treesy, 376, 100))
                                    def draw(self):
                                             self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)
                                             self.setDisplay.blit(self.img2)

                                    def load(self, filename):
                                             self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\background.png').convert_alpha()
                                             self.img2 = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\trees1.png').convert_alpha()


                            def detectCollision(sprite1, sprite2):
                                    if sprite1.colliderect(sprite2):
                                            print("worked")
                            player = Player()              
                            background = Background()
                            def gameLoop():



                                imgx = 10
                                imgy = 10
                                lead_x_change = 0
                                lead_y_change = 0
                                move_variable = 5

                                while True:



                                    pygame.display.flip()

                                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                                        #print (event)

                                        if event.type == QUIT:
                                            pygame.quit()
                                            sys.exit()
                                        setDisplay.blit(background.img, [0, 0])
                                        setDisplay.blit(background.img2, [0, 0])
                                        setDisplay.blit(player.img, [player.imgx, player.imgy])


                                        if player.rect.colliderect(background.treesrect):
                                                print("collided")

                                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                                lead_x_change = -move_variable
                                                player.x -= 10
                                            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                                                lead_y_change = -move_variable
                                            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                                player.imgx += 10
                                                player.x += 10
                                            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                                                lead_y_change = move_variable
                                                player.y += 10
                                        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                                            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                                lead_x_change = 0
                                            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                                                lead_y_change = 0
                                            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                                lead_x_change = 0
                                            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                                                lead_y_change = 0
                                        print(player.x, player.y)

                                        player.imgx += lead_x_change
                                        player.imgy += lead_y_change
                                    pygame.display.flip()
                                    pygame.display.update()

                            gameLoop()

                            #start (0, 71)
                            #length (376, 71)
                            #width (0, 168)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be due to the fact that, in the class Player, self.rect isn't right. Instead try:

`self.rect = self.img.get_rect()`

also, in your main loop, why are you blit-ing stuff in the event for loop?
Only put the key presses in `for event in pygame.event.get()`
There are other things that are very wrong in the code.
May I recommend [this excellent tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/) for making games with sprites in pygame.